# How to retain previous entered data in h:inputText?

Tags: javascript, jsf, browser, autofill

I'm using JSF 1,2 and I want the browser to retain previously entered values in h:inputText.

```
<h:inputText
id="testContact"
value="#{ObjectBeanHolder.testContact.targetAddress}"                           
onkeypress="if(event.keyCode==13) {setTimeout(function() {jQuery('input[id$=startTestButtonId]').click()}, 100);  return false;} "
styleClass="text-input testContact"  required="true"
label="#{fieldTitle}">
```

Is it possible? Or should I use another component to make a simple conservation,
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsers are keeping data for autocomplete on fields based on the website and input ID (when defined).

In the JSF case, `form` and `input` have automatically generated ID's when they are not defined. ID's can change at each application deployment, that is why it is not working in some case. To prevent this, one way is to define ID's to `form` and `input` that you want to activate autocomplete.

Note : The browser also need a *submit* to keep these values.

Comment: All the appropriate components and forms have static ID and names, but  it isn't working. None of the h:outputText is not working as I would like.

Answer (score 0):

I found that a4j command buttons which I use have "return false;" statement in onclick event. So submit and autocomplete don't work on the page.